# Wordpress function : get_posts

Tags: wordpress, posts

Crazy night! ;P

I'm devoliping a plugin with Wordpress and I'm lost looking for a function.

What I did is,

```
$args = array("meta_key" => "email", "meta_value" =>$email);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

I did that in order to filter custom fields with the same email,

```
if (count($posts) < 0){ // do something }
```

The problem is that **get_posts didn't work with custom posts**,

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'reserva', "meta_key" => "wpcf-email", "meta_value" =>$email);
```

I like to find something like **get_posts** in order to count it.

I think I have  a bad solution,: to loop it, but I want to array it.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use [meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) in your arguments array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want  post related to meta_key and meta_value  so please use this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, I will check it now,

As I said tonight i did an ugly solution,

I made a loop with a counter in porder to find if a custom fields exist.

Here is the ugly code,

```
<?php // Find matches in csutom post types
$my_consulta = array(
  'post_type'     => 'reserva',
  'post_status'   => 'draft',
  'post_key'   => 'wpcf-email',
  'meta_value'   => $email,                       
);                  


$wp_query = new WP_Query($my_consulta);
$count = 0; 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $count = $count + 1;
    endwhile;

    if ($count == 0){ 

        //No matches        

    } else {

    //There is one or more matches

    } 
?>
```

Is a good way?

Best regards,
Cristian